# AngularJS: ng-repeat displaying data incorrectly

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I am just learning to use JavaScript, AngularJS, and Parse, so please, if I am improperly doing anything, say so. I want to learn as much as possible.

I have an assignment where I am instructed to use Parse and AngularJS. I want to display each `company` in my `companies` object, and then the rating that each one has. In Parse these are stored as two separate objects with a relation.

I've finally been able to get the ratings calculated, however Angular is overwriting the data for the ratings. It is displaying the last rating calculated, rather than each rating. The `console.log(total)` is producing accurate numbers in the console.

Here is the code inside my controller for retrieving `companies`:

```
function getCompanies() {
    new Parse.Query(Companies).find({
        success: function(results) {
            for (var i = 0; i < results.length; i++) {
                results[i].relation("ratings").query().find({
                    success: function(ratings) {
                        // retrieve stars and calculate average rating
                        var total = 0;
                        for (var o = 0; o < ratings.length; o++) {
                            var stars = parseInt(ratings[o].attributes.stars);
                            total += stars;
                        }
                        total = total / ratings.length; // get average rating

                        $scope.$apply(function() {
                            $scope.companies = results.map(function(obj) {
                                console.log(total); // produces correct results
                                return {name: obj.get("name"), rating: total, parseObject: obj};
                            })
                        });
                    }
                });
            }
        }
    });
}
```

In my `view` I am using the following code:

```
<div ng-repeat="company in companies">
    <h1>{{company.name}}</h1>
    <h3>Rating: {{company.rating}}</h3>
</div>
```

Right now, if I had two `companies` and they had `ratings` of 2 and 4, right now Angular displays 4 for both. However, the `console.log(total)` will display 2 and 4.

If my code is way off, please tell me, I want to learn as much as possible. Any help is greatly appreciated, thank you.

Answer (score 0):

can you try a code something like below,

```
success: function(results) {
    for (var i = 0; i < results.length; i++) {
        var result = results[i];
        results[i].relation("ratings").query().find({
            success: function(ratings) {
                //calculate total here;
                //var total = your logic to calculate the total
                //then store the total in the result object
                result.total = total;
            }
        })
    }
    $scope.$apply(function() {
        $scope.companies = results.map(function(obj) {
            console.log(total); // produces correct results
            return {name: obj.get("name"), rating: obj.total, parseObject: obj};
        })
    });
}
```